# Django dynamically generated form sets. Deleted forms throwing validation error

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms, formset

I have an inline formset created with inlineformset_factory. Here is a simplified example.

```
#models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobType)
    price = models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('owner', 'job_type'),)

#forms.py
formset = inlineformset_factory(User, MyModel, fields=('job_type', 'price'))
```

I am using javascript to dynamically add extra forms and delete forms from my formset. When you click to delete a form it is hidden. I'm then submitting the forms with AJAX and sending back errors if necessary.

This all works fine except for one detail. MyModel has a unique together condition. If someone deletes a preexisting form (so it is hidden) and then adds another form with the same job_type and submits, django throws a uniqueness validation error even though one of the forms is being deleted.

I thought I could fix this by clearing the job_type field on the deleted form but it then throws a 'this field is required' error AND still throws the uniqueness error.

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Further research reveals the error is present in the admin interface as well. If you include an inline with a uniqueness condition to a model and then try and delete AND create an inline object with the same values, it throws the uniqueness error. So I guess this is a feature of django's formset validation. Although I'm not sure what the advantage of this behaviour is so maybe it is a bug. It is much more obvious whats going on when the deleted forms aren't hidden though.

Still, any help on getting round this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "when you click to delete a form it is hidden"? If a form is being deleted, then the POST data needs to have it marked as for deletion. See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) of the formset docs for more info. It might be helpful to get the page working without javascript first, then add the functionality to add/delete forms.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, as part of my javascript, when you click delete button, the form is marked as deleted and hidden. The page does work without javascript, I think the error is just less incomprehensible to the user if the form isn't hidden when its giving an error.